# How to add FLAG_SECURE on Android 10 - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project and I need to add a FLAG_SECURE on Android.

Currently, this is the code on my main activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }

  public override fun onPause() {
      super.onPause()
      getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
  }

  public override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
  }
}
```

This is working fine except with Android 10.

Examples:

Android 9:
[image]

Android 10:
[image]

Comment: I am also having this problem and waiting for a solution

Comment: @AbdurahmanPopal got any solution for this?

Comment: any solution guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve same with flutter plugin [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager)

add Plugin

```
dependencies:
   flutter_windowmanager: ^0.2.0
```

import package in main file

```
import 'package:flutter_windowmanager/flutter_windowmanager.dart';
```

Add this line based on your need

```
 await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Its done...